# What is the $form->getExtraData() method useful for?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am getting acquainted with the Symfony Form class API.

One thing I do not get is this method:

```
/**
 * Returns the extra data.
 *
 * @return array The submitted data which do not belong to a child
 */
public function getExtraData()
{
    return $this->extraData;
}
```

I cannot get this method to return any value. It always returns an empty array when I try to post an unmapped/unrecognized input.

Please, help me understand what the real-life usecase for this method would be. When does data become 'extra'?

A code example would be ideal.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extra data contains the submitted values of all fields which we don not have in our Form

Suppose you have a simple form with some form children

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
     ->add('form_child')
     ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
     ->getForm();
```

After rendering this form we will get something like that

```
<form name="form" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="form_form_child" name="form[form_child]" />
   <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If we submitted this form and tried to retrieve the value of `$form->getData()` and `$form->getExtraData()` we will get something like that:

```
$form->getData()
----------------
array (size=1)
  'form_child' => string 'value_child' (length=11)


$form->getExtraData()
---------------------
array (size=0)
  empty
```

The the value of the input `form_child` is stored in `data` because we created the form with the same name `->add('form_child')`

Let's modify our client side form structure and add a new input

```
...
<input type="text" id="extra_form_child" name="form[extra_child]" />
...
```

After submitting the form with the extra input we will get:

```
$form->getData()
----------------
array (size=1)
  'form_child' => string 'value_child' (length=11)


$form->getExtraData()
---------------------
array (size=1)
  'extra_child' => string 'extra_child_value' (length=17)
```